# probability problem about the function of random variables

Tags: probability

X,Y~N(0,$\sigma^{2}$),$U=X^{2}+Y^{2}$    V=$\frac{X}{\sqrt{X^{2}+Y^{2}}}$,1.proof that U,V is independent,2.$\theta=arcsinV$,please proof $\theta$~$R(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: Here is a hint compute pdf of $U$ and pdf of $V$ and the the joint and compare. also if you provide more insight and work done then you will garner more help :).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/641559/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2017359/321264

Answer (score 1):

first, this problem needs to add **X,Y is independent**

Here is my immature trial:

1.$x=v \sqrt{u},y=\pm\sqrt{u(1-v^{2})},J(u,v)=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-v^{2}}}.$
density function $g(u,v)=f(v \sqrt{u},\pm\sqrt{u(1-v^{2})})|\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-v^{2}}}|$=$\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^{2}}e^{-\frac{u}{2\sigma^{2}}}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-v^{2}}}$,so it is safely to say U,Y is independent

2.density function $l(v)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^{2}}e^{-\frac{u}{2\sigma^{2}}}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-v^{2}}}du=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-v^{2}}}$,$\theta=sinv$,so $h(\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi} $.
which is half of the density function $R(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}),\frac{1}{\pi}$.I can't find the where is wrong.