# Let $Q, R \thicksim \textrm{Normal}(0,1)$. $U = Q^2 + R^2$ and $V = \frac{Q}{\sqrt{Q^2 + R^2}}$. Are $U$ and $V$ independent?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

So we have $Q$ and $R$ i.i.d. and distributed standard normally. $U = Q^2 + R^2$ and $V = \frac{Q}{\sqrt{Q^2 + R^2}}$.

I now recognize that $U$ is a $\chi^2(2)$ distribution and that $V$ is a Beta distribution. However, how do I show that they are independent?

Comment: So many typos... $\sim$ or $=$? $U=Q+R$ or $U=Q^2+R^2$? "Cauchy distribution" for a random variable with values in $(-1,1)$? "Linearly" independent?

Comment: @Did Sorry. The $\thicksim$'s are from my prompt. The inclusion of the term linear is because I am simultaneously working on a linear algebra problem. Yes, I did not know about the support of Cauchy -- it should have been denoted a beta distribution instead.

Comment: Isn't this first and foremost your own responsability to produce a decent question if you want to see it answered?

Comment: @Did, of course it is. Yes, I made some sloppy mistakes that you pointed out, which brought to my attention that I had been careless. I thank you for that.

Comment: Not to mention, correcting the typos that have been explicitely mentioned to you... Why don't you?

Comment: @Did, I had an open tab where I was making the corrections. I seem to have struck a nerve and apologize for it, but what made you think I wasn't going to go through with correcting the typos? Again, I am sorry and mean no offense. Have a nice day and thank you for your help.

Comment: @potpie Just fix the title and $\sim$ symbols.

Comment: @d.k.o Thank you. My problem set prompt used exclusively $\sim$'s without equal signs for $U = Q^2 + R^2$ and such. Is that technically an incorrect usage of the $\sim$ symbol?

Comment: In statistics $X\sim D$ usually means that $X$ has the prob. distribution $D$ (i.e. $X\sim N(0,1)$), which is not your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually follows from @Did's comment given in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016419/finding-pdf-of-z-thicksim-q-sqrtq2-r2-where-q-r-thicksim-n0-1/), i.e. if $(X,\Theta)$ is $(Q,R)$ in [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform), then

$$
U=X^2,\quad V = \cos(\Theta),
$$

and $X$ and $\Theta$ are independent.